# Node js app gets stuck while routing

Tags: node.js

I have the following server.js file

```js
var express = require("express"),
    http = require("http"),
    app;

app = express();

//set up a static file directory to use for detaulf routing
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/client"));

http.createServer(app).listen(3000);

app.get("/hello",function(req,res){
    res.set("hello team!");
});
```

In the /client directory, I have a file called "index.html", so when I go to localhost:3000/index.html, this file is displayed, this is what I expect.

But if I then go to localhost:3000/hello the page never loads and gets stuck on "waiting for localhost" until it times out with a "no data received" error message.

If I remove the line of code for /client and just leave the routes, then it works fine. So it sounds to me like it's getting stuck trying to find "/hello" under my /client directory, but if i understand correctly, the way this works is if the file is not found on that directory, the server should try to use the other routes.

Thoughts?

Comment: Do you have a file called 'hello' inside 'client' directory?

Comment: use `res.send('hello team!')`

Comment: Is it res.send or res.set. I can't find response.set() in documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue in `/hello` route. You used `res.set("hello team!");` which is used to set HTTP header for response, not for sending the response.

Instead use `res.send('hello team!');` to send response to client.

Reference: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.set

Comment: Correct, there was a minor typo. Thanks!