# Node Express server stuck on loading

Tags: html, node.js, express

I recently started learning node.js and have a bit of trouble finding the issue here. I made an express application which console.logs out a string when a button on the web page is pressed, but when I press the button on the web page it starts reloading and never stops. Here's my code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var port = 42069;

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/", (req, res)=>{
    console.log("Button pressed!");
});

app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`Running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Hope you guys can help! :)

Comment: Can you share the code that posts the POST request?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771771/node-js-app-gets-stuck-while-routing

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate as I don't see the resemblence in questions, on the other side I don't know much about node so it could be the same thing oof

Answer (score 2):

This is your get handler:

> ```
> app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
>     res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
> });
> ```

When it receives a request it uses the response to send a file.

This is your post handler:

> ```
> app.post("/", (req, res)=>{
>     console.log("Button pressed!");
> });
> ```

When it receives a request it logs to the console and does nothing else.

You don't send any kind of response.

The browser never stops reloading because you never send it the response it is waiting for.

You need to respond with something appropriate for the request.

Answer (score 1):

What you're saying is exactly what is supposed to happen, based on your code. When you press the button on the web page, the code specifies it to only log something in the console. If you want it to log something and then re-render the page, do this:

```
    app.post("/", (req, res)=>{
       console.log("Button pressed!");
       res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
    });
```

as the comment below states, spot on! it's a common mistake and baffling to debug. If you have a handler like your `post()` handler, you must either call `next()` or call some `res.whatever()` method, or your browser will sit there waiting!

Comment: Yes, it's a common mistake and baffling to debug. If you have a handler like your `post()` handler, you *must* either call `next()` or call some `res.whatever()` method, or your browser will sit there waiting.

Comment: spot on! I'll add this to my answer for more visibility!

Comment: Thank you man! Very helpful. Also, could you, if you want no pressure, maybe send me a link to some good documentation/tutorial, the ones I've found are a bit hard for my tiny brain :D

Comment: @Coenicorn np! tbh, I don't have any. I learned myself through YouTube and trial and error. Just google nodeJs projects that are of interest to you, and follow them, and then just practice!

Comment: Thank you so much! As a matter of fact, I'm very good at watching videos on youtube :D. Usually I'm not so productive tho lol.